# What is the correct way to "serialize" functions in javascript for later use

Tags: javascript, json, function, object

I have a "library" of objects that I want to load on the fly from a database. Each object comes with its own special functions that are called at specific times depending on the objects type. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this, although its been pointed out that this doesn't work:

```
library = {
  "myObj" : {"name" : "myObj", "type" : "myType", "function" : function () { } } //, etc
}
```

The string `"myObj"` is passed around my program quite a bit, but I only have to access certain values of the object at a time, and in some circumstances there's a specific function that needs to be run. The problem is that I'm looking at hundreds, and eventually thousands, of potential objects that could exist with varying functions.

What is the "right" way to store a function to be called like this. I know that calling eval can be very unsafe during execution, enabling xss attacks and whatnot. I really want to avoid a massive switch statement or the bloated loading of additional functions. I'd also like the solution to be as concise as possible.

This can't be the first time this has come up. ;/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no right way. This is a flat out bad idea.

Comment: Unless it is what he needs to do, in which case it is a problem he's trying to solve in the best way. Yeesh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use eval to recreate the function after loading it as a string. So if you deserialize an object `myObj` from JSON, and you have a property:

```
myObj = {
    ....
    function: "function() { ... }"
}
```

you can very easily turn it to a real function:

```
eval("myObj.func = " + myObj.func);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kceTr/

Oh - I am not sure if that was an edit or I missed it before - but re: eval.

Eval is a tool. You want to store a function in a database. It really doesn't make much difference if you have to "eval" to turn it into code, or there was some other magic way to do it: if someone can change the data in your DB, then they can change a function.

If you need to store a function, then eval is your tool. It's not "bad" by nature, it's bad because it's easy to misuse. Whether you use it well or not is up to you.

Remember anything running on the client is still just running on the client. There's nothing a malicious person could do with eval, that they couldn't do with the Chrome debugger a lot more easily. Anyone can always run any code they want on the client, it's up to your server to decide how to handle what it receives. There's nothing safe on the client in the first place...

Comment: So, its fine to use as long as I'm careful. :/ -:: :: ::- I've seen a lot of people implying that it should never be used, as if it were goto.

Comment: Eh, I'm sure a lot of people think JSONP is bad too. The whole web works on hacks. There's really no other way to accomplish what you want to do, at least that I can think of.

Comment: I'll use this as a working model for now, but I'm going to wait to see if anyone turns up a better idea that keeps me out of the shark tank

Comment: @Kirk BTW, `goto`s used *improperly* are a bad idea.  Of themselves, they are just a tool -- and pretty much the ONLY way to branch in assembly.  A lot of people just repeat dogma without understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the prototype of the object is a half thought I have.

You've got your library like

```
library = {
  "myObj" : {"name" : "myObj", "type" : "myType", "function" : function () { } } //, etc
}
```

You've got an object (let's call it `theObj`) that you know is a `myObj` (due to a string maybe? property?)

```
theObj.__proto__ = library["myObj"];
```

That way you can execute

```
theObj.function(...);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h2an/2/) example (it's *rough*!). Also, be careful with **proto**, it's deprecated ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) ([2](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/))

As to serializing the functions, can you get them in using a script tag that points to something serverside that slurps them from the db and returns the js? Just include them inline as you render the page (in a script block)? Or, if all else fails, eval should work, as long as you know that the functions you've got stored in the database are clean and safe.

Comment: I'm not using deprecated functions when there's no reason to do so. :: :: :: Using php to auto insert them into the javascript is enticing. I will need to think on it. I sometimes forget that php is the first pass and lets me manipulate not just the page, but also the code.

Comment: property, not function, but yeah. There's blessed ways of futzing with the prototype that don't involve `__proto__`. If it makes you squirm, php'ing them into the page and eval will be much better :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no right way to do this, because its not generally a good idea.

HOWEVER, if you want to do it anyways you can simply extend the prototype of Function with a `.toJSON` method.

```
Function.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return this.toString(); }
```

Then you can simply use JSON.stringify and functions will be serialized as strings.

Its generally a not good idea in most cases. There are very few circumstances where you want to do this and even then, there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to serialize the object's properties when you "sleep" it, and "waking" the object by reattaching its properties to a new instance of the object with the appropriate methods defined.

Comment: I'm not really sleeping the object. I basically want to have a ton of very similar objects that I can load from my database that all have unique ids and all have fairly unique functions. If I have to create a function for every object I wake up based on its id, I'm still going to have a massive switch statement, which is what I'm trying to avoid. :: :: :: Perhaps what I'm looking for is a way to dynamically load a class?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing with it is just fine. However, if i were you, for readability and tidyness, i would rather have the function created outside and simply have it assigned  to your object key.

You don't need eval here. Instead do it this way whenever you want  access to the stored function -

library.myObj.function()

Comment: Elaborate please: "i would rather have the function created outside and simply have it assigned to your object key."

Comment: @Kirk

var library = {
        myObj: {
           name : "myObj", 
           type : "myType",
      }
   };

library.myObj.function=function()
{
 alert(123455)
};

library.myObj.function(); 


//if you use eval in your code, NOT ONLY IS YOUR CODE VULNERABLE TO MALICIOUS ATTACK, BUT ALSO YOU WONT BE ABLE TO OBFUSCATE/MINIFY YOUR LIBRARY using standard obfuscator/minifier (for instance, google closure)

Answer (score 0):

- You do your best in parameterising your functions, so that you end up
  with as little typologies as possible.
- Store them on the server in individual JS files, then load the needed file dynamically, by name.
- In the JSON, only store the name of the file that contains the function that you need. And, of course, you will be caching already loaded files, to go easy on the server.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of code would go in such a function? I have a hard time trying to imagine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only really serialise a whole file with `require` calls in it. If you do that, you can create a module, exports and module.exports, eval the file with a function surrounding it and snag the module.exports out of it.

It's not exactly secure, but for that you need to use something like [VM2](http://npmjs.com/vm2) and [value-censorship](http://npmjs.com/value-censorship) (which I've been working on) to avoid them calling eval() and owning your machine or the entire network.