# Why custom elements not support attributes as an object?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

**I am trying to pass data attribute in custom element as an object but while receiving inside attachedCallback method getting value "[object object]" in a string form.**

So can anyone help me to figure out what is the work around to get the attributes as an object inside custom-element(web component).

> code sample

```
<script>
class myElements extends HTMLElement {
    createdCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello</h1>`;
    }
    attachedCallback() {
        console.log(this.getAttribute('data'));
    }
}

 document.registerElement('my-element', myElements);
</script>
```

> custom element tag

```
<script>
    var object = { key1: 111, key2: 222, key3: function(){return "hi"}, key4:[1,2,3]};

   function changeHandler() {
    page('/default', function() {
        // some logic to decide which route to redirect to
        if (admin) {
            page.redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            page.redirect('/guest');
        }
    });
}

</script>

<my-element data="object" onchange="changeHandler"></my-element>
```

Note: suppose that `<my-element>` is a dropdown which gives user option to choose some value.

**Solution: Still no native solution in custom-element specs([v0](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) and [v1](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements)).**

Since Custom Elements doesn't support data binding so we need a sugaring layer for that (e.g., Polymer or SkateJS) as mention by @tony in the comment.

Comment: Missing quotes at value at `data-*` attribute. What is purpose of storing function at attribute of `html` element?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix React syntax with custom elements. That won't work.

Comment: @Bergi No I just want to achieve React like functionality/feature also i had edited my question to minimize confusion

Comment: You could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697863/what-is-the-correct-way-to-serialize-functions-in-javascript-for-later-use

Comment: @guest271314, the main purpose is to pass functions in attribute as a callBack handler
e.g. <my-element data="object" onchange="changeHandler"></my-element>

Comment: @coder _"the main purpose is to pass functions in attribute as a callBack handler "_ What issue are you having? You could define `object` as a global variable, and use bracket notation to reference `object`.

Comment: Well `object` and `changeHandler` are just strings in those attribute values, there's no relation to your JS code. Please show us the exact code you used to obtain `[object object]`.

Comment: @guest271314 The problem is I have dropdown(as a custom-element), so the requirement is when user choose any value from the dropdown I want to change the route of the page and also I want to this action outside of the component lifecycle(dropdown) to separate app logic from the component(dropdown) logic.

e.g function changeHandler(){
    /*change route*/
 page(./nextPage);
}

Comment: @coder See original Question _"Why custom elements not support attributes as an object? 
I am trying to pass data attribute in custom element as an object but while receiving inside attachedCallback method getting value "[object object]" in a string form."_? Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle to reproduce _""[object object]""_?

Comment: @guest271314, Agreed but the root problem is how to pass objects/functions as an attribute. ok i will post very soon the actual code snippet.

Comment: @coder See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @coder As others have noted, attribute values can only be strings. What you're seeking is effectively data binding, which Custom Elements itself doesn't support out of the box. You would need a sugaring layer for that (e.g., [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) or [SkateJS](https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/tree/master/docs/api#attribute)).

Comment: @tony19 Thank to confirm that this is the missing feature in custom-element , I also wonder why custom-element spec missing this important features. Yesterday I have also read custom-element v1 spec but it also have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try by converting object to JSON string,

```
var object = { key1: 111, key2: 222};
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Then when you want to get the value, parse it back to object

```
JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu for your comment and sorry for implete object format....but what about this types of object var object = { key1: 111, key2: 222, key3: function(){return "hi"}, key4:[1,2,3]};

Comment: suggested approach(stringify and parse) doesn't work for the object having functions as a value inside.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Elements does not modify the standard HTML element attribute behaviour which is always of type `string`.

Because of that, you shoud instead either:

1. Send a  `change` Event from your custom element that will trigger the `onchange` handler.
2. Register you object/function callback via a custom element method.
3. Modify a *state* attribute that will be observed (with `Mutation Observer`) by its container.

If you want to use attribute anyways you can always use `eval()`.

---

Example with solution 1 with call to `changeHandler()`:

```js
//define custom element
class DropDown extends HTMLElement 
{
  connectedCallback ()
  {
    var span = this.querySelector( 'span' )

    //define ul list
    var ul = this.querySelector( 'ul' )

    ul.onclick = ev => {
      if ( this.value != ev.target.textContent )
      {
        this.value = ev.target.textContent
        this.setAttribute( 'value', this.value )
        span.textContent = this.value 
        this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'change' ) )
      }
    }

    //show or hide
    this.onclick = ev => ul.classList.toggle( 'show' )
    
  }

}
customElements.define( 'drop-down', DropDown )
```

```css
drop-down  {
  position: relative ;
  cursor: pointer ;
  display: inline-block ;
}
drop-down > span {
  border: 1px solid #aae ;
  padding: 2px 5px ;
}
drop-down > ul {
  position: absolute ;
  top: 4px ; left: 5px ;
  list-style: none ;
  outline: 1px solid #aae ;
  padding: 0 ;
  display: inline-block ;
  opacity: 0 ;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out ;
  background: white ;
  visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 10 ;
}
drop-down > ul.show {
  opacity: 1 ;
  visibility: visible ;
}
drop-down > ul > li {
  padding: 2px 5px ;
}
drop-down > ul > li:hover {
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow ;
}
```

```html
<drop-down onchange="changeHandler()">
  <span>select value</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Chrome</li>
    <li>Firefox</li>
    <li>Opera</li>
    <li>Safari</li>
  </ul>
</drop-down>

<script>
  function changeHandler ()
  {
    console.log( 'changeHandler()', event.target.value )
  }
</script>
```