# Can you dynamically define properties in a template string in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Can I pass in a template string and also dynamically pass in a property so that I can make it reactive? In the example below I would like message to be reactive, but I don't want to have to predefine it on the data option.

```
<div id="vue">
 <component :is="string && {template:string}"/>
</div>

new Vue({
    el:'#vue',
    data(){
    return {
    string:undefined,
   }
  },
  created(){
    //setTimeout to simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(()=> this.string = '<div><h1 v-for="n in 1">Hello!    </h1><input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me"><p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>    </div>', 1000)
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kxtsvtro/5/

Comment: Are you looking for [`v-bind`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Value-Bindings)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the `data` in the same way you specify the template: just interpolate it into the component spec.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data() {
    return {
      string: undefined,
      dataObj: undefined
    }
  },
  created() {
    //setTimeout to simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.string = '<div><h1 v-for="n in 1">Hello!</h1><input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me"><p>Message is: {{ message }}</p></div>';
      this.dataObj = {
        message: 'initial'
      };
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <component :is="string && {template:string, data: function() { return dataObj}}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can I also pass in a function dynamically for computed?
   `computed: {
   }`

Comment: I would think so. Give it a shot. You could have a single data object for the entire component spec and populate whatever pieces of it you need to.

Comment: Is there a way to load or populate the entire componentspec (AJAX)? I'm hung up on passing in a computed function. I might be going about this all wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/ot9dh97u/22/

Comment: Ajax doesn't support functions. You would have to [serialize and unserialize the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697863/what-is-the-correct-way-to-serialize-functions-in-javascript-for-later-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props), but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it :) here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#vue',
    data(){
    return {
        string:undefined,
      message:''
    }
  },
  created(){
    //setTimeout to simulate ajax call
    setTimeout(()=> this.string = '<div><h1 v-for="n in 1">Hello!</h1><input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me"><p>Message is: {{ message }}</p></div>', 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script> 
<div id="vue">
  <component :is="string && {template:string, props:['message']}" :message="message"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to set a dynamic prop on the component? I don't want it to be always called "message".

Comment: See Roy's solution i think it is better

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a component with a `<slot>` that you can dump a custom component into. If you're trying to compose components that's probably the easiest way to do it.